# Mysql2 Error while accessing rails app via nginx and unicorn

Tags: mysql, nginx, ruby-on-rails-4, unicorn

I have setup my production server and the rails app is deployed using capistrano 3.1 on nginx and unicorn on Ubuntu Server 12.04LTS. The app is working fine when accessed via normal rails server but whenever I try to run the server via unicorn its says that it cant access some tables in the database. Attached is the snapshot of the error and the snapshot of the database queries.[image]

[image]

Comment: You created the DB and ran migrations against the production environment in your cap task, yes?

Comment: yes I did that. Shouldnt I be doing that.

Comment: I disabled that, dropped the database and re ran the same process, unicorn tries to execute some queries and gets these errors.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above in the comments, I cleared the database, the folders and re-ran the deployment after removing the migration extension for capistrano and everything worked just fine.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work well. The later migrations doesn't apply