# Capistrano doesn't run all migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano

I am running a unicorn app server with nginx and Rails 4.1.1. The provisioning to the staging and the production are done by capistrano 3.1.0

The is the Capfile

```
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Includes default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/console'

# Includes tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
#
# For documentation on these, see for example:
#
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
#   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
#   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails
#

require 'capistrano/rvm'
# require 'capistrano/rbenv'
# require 'capistrano/chruby'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
#require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
#require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'

# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/**/*.rb').each { |r| import r }
```

Works fine but there is one problem, when I manually try to seed the databases, it says the most of the later migrations are not applied. I checked and I found that none of the migrations apart from the initial migration are not applied. Wondering why. Any hints?

Maybe this can help - the unicorn rb file

```
root = "<%= current_path %>"
working_directory root
pid "#{root}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.log"

listen "/tmp/unicorn.<%= fetch(:full_app_name) %>.sock"
worker_processes <%= fetch(:unicorn_worker_count) %>
timeout 40
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|
   defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  # Quit the old unicorn process
  old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"
  if File.exists?(old_pid) && server.pid != old_pid
    puts "We've got an old pid and server pid is not the old pid"
    begin
      Process.kill("QUIT", File.read(old_pid).to_i)
      puts "killing master process (good thing tm)"
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
      puts "unicorn master already killed"
      # someone else did our job for us
    end
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  port = 5000 + worker.nr
  child_pid = server.config[:pid].sub('.pid', ".#{port}.pid")
  system("echo #{Process.pid} > #{child_pid}")
   defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Comment: Why is this commented out? `#require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'`

Comment: did you checked that Capistrano ran `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: I know unicorn is creating tables the moment I am restarting unicorn. Capistrano never ran db:migrate. Unicorn is creating the tables. How do I stop that

Comment: Thats why I commented the rails/migrations because in that some other error was coming http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21958491/mysql2-error-while-accessing-rails-app-via-nginx-and-unicorn/21984909#21984909

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine now. Removed the before_fork and after_fork section and it works fine now with rails/migration from capistrano in place.